# How to delete Azure Spatial Anchor after detected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, azure-spatial-anchors

I develop an unity application and I am working with azure spatial anchors. I found no possibility to delete a detected cloudAnchor. I tried this:

```
    protected void OnCloudAnchorLocated(AnchorLocatedEventArgs args)
    {
        CloudSpatialAnchor nextCsa = args.Anchor;


        ...
        if (nextCsa != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("BEFORE DELETE");
            await CloudManager.DeleteAnchorAsync(nextCsa);
            Debug.Log("AFTER DELETE");
        }
    }
```

I get this in the console:

> StoreAndWatcherTrackedState::TryRemoveAsync for SpatialAnchor:
>   6b77de6e-d8ba-44ce-b7cc-1f1d09bcc7a5

And this error:

> OnError - The specified spatial anchor is already associated with a different store

So I have three questions:

**1. What is the meaning of the error?**

**2. Is it possible to delte detected anchors from azure?**

**3. If yes what is the correct approach?**

Answer (score 2):

I cannot answer your first question. But I gave you my rough idea on how to delete anchor. I used `List<CloudSpatialAnchor>` to save located anchor locally. Then you can create a button to delete all the located anchor.

```
void Start(){
    ...
    List<CloudSpatialAnchor> nextCsa = new List<CloudSpatialAnchor>();
    ...
}

protected void OnCloudAnchorLocated(AnchorLocatedEventArgs args)
{
    ...
    nextCsa.Add(args.Anchor);
    ...
}

public void DeleteAnchor(){
    foreach(CloudSpatialAnchor anchor in nextCsa){
          await this.CloudManager.DeleteAnchorAsync(anchor);
    } 
}
```

[image]

I hope this helps.

*+++++++ EDIT +++++++*

I might understand the solve for the first question.
The error you received might be connected to the ongoing Event on [Cloud Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.spatialanchors.cloudspatialanchorsession). You try to delete anchor before the `LocateAnchorsCompleted` Event are completed. So, I suggest you to complete locating the anchor, stop the Watcher afterwards using

```
args.Watcher.Stop();
```

and delete the spatial anchor afterward.